# Print Fortran write(*,*) in R console

Tags: r, gfortran

I am trying to call an exe file created with Fortran and the gfortran compiler in R. However, R does not show the same output on my two computers.

Let's say I have a very simple Fortran code :

```
program Main
write(*,*) 'Hello World !'
end
```

I created an exe file using gfortran, giving : hello.exe
Then, when i call the exe in R using :

```
shell('hello.exe')
```

on my first computer, i get the 'Hello World !' printed in the R console, while on the other one, the code works, but nothing is printed, and I don't understand why. I guess something must be different between the two computers by I don't know what (both use the same R and gfortran versions).

Comment: How do these two systems differ?

Comment: The two computers use Windows 7 64-bit. They have the same configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution. I thought that both computers shared the same version of R but it was not the case. The one that prints the message runs with R 3.5.0 while the other runs with a previous version.

Surprisingly, it is apparently not possible to display the messages with previous versions of R.

Comment: Can you specify exact version of the "previous version"?